# IsPublishable is ignored in .NET 5 unit test projects

Tags: .net, msbuild, .net-5, dotnet-sdk, dotnet-publish

I have some .NET projects in a solution.
When I publish them, I'd like to publish just the DLL of my *src* projects, not the *test* ones.

Both https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/13365 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish#msbuild mention IsPublishable can be used to do so.

IsPublishable seems to be ignored for .NET 5 project.

I set at any test project the following

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>$(ApplicationTargetFramework)</TargetFramework>
        <IsPublishable>false</IsPublishable>
        <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

but later, when I do a `dotnet publish -c Release -o publish` I can still see the test project `*.dll` and `deps.json`. Why? How to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably something wrong I did. It works.

```
dotnet publish -o publish
```

will publish dll for each project.

If you add `<IsPublishable>false</IsPublishable>` on some `*.csproj` it won't publish those dll.

Comment: For me it worked when I published the whole solution (*.sln) instead of every project individually (**/*.csproj)

Comment: That command at solution level publishes all the projects within the solution at once.

Comment: Yes. I meant, then it actually applied the <IsPublishable> attribute, whereas it appeared to be ignored with individual projects.

I was just saying, if someone has the same problem, they could try to switch from **/\*.csproj to *.sln

Comment: Ah I see. Well, it kind of make sense to be overridden imo. If you set a `*.csproj` as `IsPublishable` to `false` and then want to explicitly publish it with `dotnet publish` on that specific project, I'd like it to be published regardless. Not sure if it's as per design though. I rarely publish a single project.